# Samsung Galaxy S having internal sd card problems

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, internal-storage

I have `Samsung Galaxy SLCD` having android 2.2.1 which is around one and half year old. Around one month back my it started showing message in notification bar '`internal sd card removed unexpectedly`' and after that sometimes phone hanged and I got black screen with samsung written like we get at boot time and sometimes there is multiple '`force close`' pop-ups of different apps on phone. Whenever phone gets hanged or it automatically shutdown I am able to restart it only after removing battery and putting it back again and it takes long time to boot up every time I restart.

Now from last 3-4 days I am having following problems that were not there earlier-

1. If I install an app from market or through eclipse and I restart phone the app is not there.
2. If I uninstall an old app and I restart phone the app is not uninstalled, it is still there.
3. If I copy a file it does not show up or if I transfer a file through Bluetooth it is gone after restart of phone.

However I am able to open old files or app. I don't have external SD card on my phone. Is problem with internal SD card of phone or some other OS or phone related issue. Anyone know how to solve above problems.

Thanks in advance.

Anuj

Comment: To me this looks like a problem with the NAND flash memory on your internal sdcard: data which already *had* been saved, sticks, but no changes are possible (the controller might be unable to wipe blocks for some reason; you still see the changes until reboot, as they are probably still cached). If you still have warranty, I'd strongly suggest to see a service center with it, before the warranty is running out.

Comment: Thanks for replying,  as phone is out of warranty how much it will cost if the problem is related with NAND flash memory.  Is there any way to solve this problem

Comment: Well, let it put me that way: If the device is out of warranty, and it really is the NAND flash broken: Take a look at the nice new devices available meanwhile and make your choice, but don't spend your money on repair. I'd *guess* if you find a place that would repair your old SGS, it won't be cheaper than buying a new one. Sorry. But of course you can ask a repair service first, they should know.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem with my Samsung Galaxy S.  You can also get it going again by holding the "On" button for about 15 seconds.  It has been happening now for about 2 months and it was only today that I happened to be looking at it as it hanged and I saw the message about the internal SD Card, before that I thought it was a corrupt operating system or faulty battery.

The frustrating thing is that when it hangs I lose all my contacts, my text message history and my customised settings like shortcuts to certain apps on the desktop.

It also loses the default setting for connecting to the Mobile Access Point set by my mobile provider. Sometimes when it reboots people can't ring me, they think it rings once but I don't hear it ringing at all and I get no missed called.

It's funny, I notice that this post is dated December 27th and this is roughly when my phone started giving trouble, my phone is about a year and a half as well.

The advice given here by Izzy is probably the best advice for this situation but I just wanted to contribute some content here that might help more people with the same problem to find this post because unless you are looking at the phone when it crashes you will never think that the internal SD Card was at fault.  It is more likely that you will find that your phone has switched itself off or has just hung.