# Jelly Bean Update cause SD card unexpectedly removed issue

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, external-sd, samsung-galaxy-note

I have recently updated my Samsung Galaxy Note from ICS to official JellyBean Update. I am getting SD card unexpectedly removed issue after regular interval.

SD card unexpectedly removed issue is not there if phone is in charging mode or If I am listening music or playing games.

SD card unexpectedly removed issue appears only when I use phone after some time. This is very annoying please help me to fix this issue.

1. Phone: Samsung Galaxy Note
2. SD: SanDisk 32 gb.

Comment: We already have a similar question here: [SD card unexpectedly removed](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/36875/16575) (and here: [Samsung Galaxy S having internal sd card problems](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/36246/16575) -- though this one is not with JB, but it at least has some answers).

Comment: No this not the case my brother have s2 with ICS same card work fine with s2. Same card was working fine before updating my phone. But problem arise after upgrade. I googled and most of the people saying its known big Issue with Jelly Bean you should wait till next firmware upgrade.